# The approximation of first-ordered modified Bessel function of the second kind

Tags: special-functions, approximation

After analysing the outage probability of a single relay selection system, I got to the following form:
$P = 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^K {\left( \begin{array}{l}
K\\
k
\end{array} \right){{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}2\sqrt {\frac{{k{\gamma _o}{c_p}}}{{{\lambda _{SR}}{\lambda _{RD}}}}} {e^{ - \frac{{k{\gamma _o}}}{{{\lambda _{SR}}}}}}{K_1}\left( {2\sqrt {\frac{{k{\gamma _o}{c_p}}}{{{\lambda _{SR}}{\lambda _{RD}}}}} } \right)}$. When $\lambda_{SR}$ and $\lambda_{RD}$ go to infinity we can use the approximation: ${K_1}\left( x \right) \sim \frac{1}{x}$ (where ${K_1}\left( x \right)$ is the first-ordered modified Bessel function of the second kind) to get an asymptotic of the above formula to be:
$P = 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^K {\left( \begin{array}{l}
K\\
k
\end{array} \right){{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}{e^{ - \frac{{k{\gamma _o}}}{{{\lambda _{SR}}}}}}}$. However, the original and the approximation forms are not closed when $\lambda_{SR}$ and $\lambda_{RD}$ go to infinity. Here is the test figure:[image]

Can somebody give me some hint how these form behave like that?
Thank you very much.
Best Regards, Binh.

Comment: What do you mean by "the original and the approximation forms are not closed when $λ_{SR}$ and $λ_{RD}$ go to infinity"?

Answer (score 2):

Your asymptotic expansion for the Bessel function $K_1$ is wrong (from which source is it?) and therefore the resulting formula for $P$ too. The correct one is (derived from e.g. Abramowitz and Stegun 9.7.2 or http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40#i):
$$K_1(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}e^{-x}\left(1 + \frac{3}{8x}+ O(x^{-2})\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
The asymptotic expansion I used is not wrong. It is also from "Abramowitz and Stegun - page 375, Eq. 9.6.9"

Comment: The one you gave is just for the case x goes to infinity.
But, in my case, x goes to zero.

Comment: Ah, I see; sorry for the misunderstanding. With $$ x= {\frac{{k{\gamma _o}{c_p}}}{{{\lambda _{SR}}{\lambda _{RD}}}}} $$
the interesting part then is (calculated right now with Maple)
$$2\sqrt{x}K_1(2\sqrt{x}) \sim
1+(\ln x +2\gamma-1)x + O(x^2)$$
where $\gamma= 0.5772156649\dots$ is  Euler's constant. May be this improves your approximation (your current uses only the leading 1). Another problem may be the relation of your $\lambda _{SR}, \lambda _{RD}:$ Are they indendent? Or is $\lambda _{RD}$ constant? In the exponential term there is only $\lambda _{SR}$.

Comment: $\lambda_{RD}$ and $\lambda_{SR}$ are independent. $\lambda_{RD}$ is a pre-defined constant.
Thank you.

Comment: How many terms of the sum do you use, i.e. what is $K$? Note that with 'improved' approximation you will get new terms at least of order $K^2$.

Comment: K is the number of relays in the system. I used K = 4.